# How to fix 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (373, 2, 2)'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

This is my first time image classification, I have tried to classification the images that have 2 classes. My images dataset are 128*128 and I use RGB so the I thinks the dimension is 128, 128, 3. The code is

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = []
train_label = []

train_files_1 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/train_images/Atopic_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_1:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    train.append(image)
    train_label.append([0., 1.]) 

train_files_2 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/train_images/Contact_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files, )
    train.append(image)
    train_label.append([1., 0.])

train_array = np.array(train, dtype='int')
train_label_array = np.array(train_label, dtype='int')

test = []
test_label = []

test_files = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/test_images/Atopic_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in test_files:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    test.append(image)
    test_label.append([0., 1.])

test_files_2 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/test_images/Contact_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in test_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    test.append(image)
    test_label.append([1., 0.])

test_array = np.array(test, dtype='int')
test_label_array = np.array(test_array, dtype='int')

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical

x_train = train_array
y_train = train_label_array

x_test = test_array
y_test = test_label_array

x_train = x_train.reshape(373, 128, 128, 3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(95, 128, 128, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, to_categorical(y_train), validation_data = (x_test, to_categorical(y_test)), epochs = 3)
```

After run the code it show 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (373, 2, 2)' and I don't know how to fix it you can see the code in github at https://github.com/filmer2002/real_rash_project/blob/master/images_to_numpy_and_CNN_code.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have labels, with a shape different from your output layer, given to the network to train.

`to_categorical()` needs 2 parameters, `labels` and `len`, `labels` have to be `dtype=int` and smaller then `len`, and make sure that your `tensorflow` and `tensorboard` are up to date.

Try

```py
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = []
train_label = []

train_files_1 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/train_images/Atopic_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_1:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    train.append(image)
    train_label.append(1) 

train_files_2 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/train_images/Contact_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files, )
    train.append(image)
    train_label.append(0)

train_array = np.array(train, dtype=int)
train_label_array = np.array(train_label, dtype=int)

test = []
test_label = []

test_files = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/test_images/Atopic_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in test_files:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    test.append(image)
    test_label.append(1)

test_files_2 = glob.glob('/Users/filmer2002/Desktop/real_rash_project/test_images/Contact_Dermatitis/*.jpg')
for files in test_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    test.append(image)
    test_label.append(0)

test_array = np.array(test, dtype=int)
test_label_array = np.array(test_array, dtype=int)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical

x_train = train_array
y_train = train_label_array

x_test = test_array
y_test = test_label_array

x_train = x_train.reshape(373, 128, 128, 3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(95, 128, 128, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, to_categorical(y_train, 10), validation_data = (x_test, to_categorical(y_test, 10)), epochs = 3)
```

`len` given to `to_categorical` in this case is 10 because your output layer has `shape == (10,)`

Also make sure that you have equal amount of images and labels for them, you cen test that by:

```py
x_train.shape[0] == to_categorical(y_train, 10).shape[0]
True                 #should be True if everything is ok
```

And one final note: `tensorflow` works with tensors i. e. n dimensional arrays, don't use lists when working with training data, numpy arrays should be used most of the time.

EDIT:
Only 1 dimensional arrays or lists consisting of int values are ok for `to_categorical()`.

Don't try to use lists consisting of [0, 1] in `to_categorical()`, it won't work, just use 1 `to_categorical()` will convert it for you into [0, 1] elements.

Your mistake was to use lists as labels for `to_categorical()`, `to_categorical()` only accepts 1 dimensional int arrays as it's first parameter, the shape you where giving it was (number_of_labels, 2), when it only works with shape == (number_of_labels,).

OR

If you want to use lists/arrays consisting of elements like [0, 1] and your model output shape is 2, then just don't use `to_categorical()` at all.

Comment: It still has the error but this error is 'IndexError: index 117 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2' you can check my code [link] (https://github.com/filmer2002/real_rash_project/blob/master/images_to_numpy_and_CNN_code.ipynb)

Comment: make sure that your labels are `to_categorical_len` > labels > 0. also try replacing to_categorical(y_train, to_categorical_len) with to_categorical(np.array(y_train), to_categorical_len). if that fails too try to update tensorflow to 1.14.0. and if after that it still fails, ill need to see your labels then...

Comment: if the error still comes up, print out your labels and let me take a look

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and if it doesn't you have inconsistent data.

```py
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

#assert tf.__version__ == '1.14.0'

train = np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 3))
train_label = []

train_files_1 = glob.glob('/path/to/your/folder/with/data/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_1:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    img = np.array(image).astype(int).reshape(128, 128, 3)

    train = np.concatenate((train, [img]), axis=0)

    train_label.append(1) 

train_files_2 = glob.glob('/path/to/your/folder/with/data/*.jpg')
for files in train_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    img = np.array(image).astype(int)

    train = np.concatenate((train, [img]), axis=0)

    train_label.append(0)

x_train = train[1:]
y_train = to_categorical(train_label, 2)

test = np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 3))
test_label = []

test_files = glob.glob('/path/to/your/folder/with/data/*.jpg')
for files in test_files:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    img = np.array(image).astype(int)

    test = np.concatenate((test, [img]), axis=0)

    test_label.append(1)

test_files_2 = glob.glob('/path/to/your/folder/with/data/*.jpg')
for files in test_files_2:
    image = cv2.imread(files)
    img = np.array(image).astype(int)

    test = np.concatenate((test, [img]), axis=0)

    test_label.append(0)

x_test = test[1:]
y_test = to_categorical(test_label, 2)

print ('train', x_train.shape)
print ('test', x_test.shape)
print ('test labels', y_test.shape)
print ('train labels', y_train.shape)

assert x_train.shape == (len(train[1:]), 128, 128, 3)
assert x_test.shape == (len(test[1:]), 128, 128, 3)

assert y_train.shape == (len(train_label), 2)
assert y_test.shape == (len(test_label), 2)

# if you get an error about one of the asserts above => your data is not consistant

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=3)

print ('all good, all done!')
```

Note: mixing python lists and numpy arrays is very bad idea

Comment: Thanks you very much, I can train it now.

Comment: im happy that you were able to train your model, the complex math and array operations may seem complicated, but you'll get it with time!